# Computing $\int_{k=0}^{k=\frac{n-1}{n}}{\frac{1}{k}\mathbb{d}k}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

So we have the integral:

- $\int_{k=0}^{k=\frac{n-1}{n}}{\frac{1}{k}\mathrm{d}k}$

The integral of $\frac{1}{k}$ with respect to $k$ is $\ln{(k)}$ but if we try to integrate over the limits of integration we would get:

- $\ln{(\frac{n-1}{n})} - \ln{(0)}$

But, $\ln{(0)}$ is undefined...

Comment: Then consider $\int_\epsilon^\frac{n-1}{n} \frac{1}{k} \textrm{d}k$ for $\epsilon$ small but positive, and then let $\epsilon$ go to 0.

Comment: Your integral diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: @Hetebrij -- it won't help much, since $\log\varepsilon\to -\infty$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Comment: It will help, as it shows that the integral diverges.

Comment: @Hetebrij Oh, Ok.

Comment: @Hetebrij Thank you guys for the quick responses. So, if I'm understanding this correctly, I should compute $\ln{(\frac{n-1}{n})} - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}{\ln{(\epsilon)}} = \text{ some number} - \infty = -\infty$?

Comment: Almost, we have $\ln \left( \frac{n-1}{n} \right)- \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \ln (\epsilon) = \textrm{some number}- (  - \infty) = \infty$.

Comment: @Hetebrij Shoot, my mistake. Thank you guys again for the help! Very clear explanation. Now I'll just research why it is allowed to input $0$ as a limit.